# Is there a limit in the number of WebGL Textures I can load in one page session?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, textures, webgl

I'm using the [glfx.js](https://github.com/evanw/glfx.js) image effects library for a website where I have one canvas than renders an image that is constantly being replaced by a new image and then applies a filter to it.

The problem is that after a few minutes of running (after having loaded around 2300 different textures) WebGL throws this error:

```
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: bad image data
```

I've narrowed it down to this function:

```
Texture.prototype.loadContentsOf = function(element) {
  this.width = element.width || element.videoWidth;
  this.height = element.height || element.videoHeight;
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.id);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.format, this.format, this.type, element);
};
```

After the ~2,300th call to gl.texImage2D() WebGL throws an INVALID_VALUE error and then the page just crashes (with Chrome's "Aw, Snap!").

I'm destroying the textures by calling this:

```
Texture.prototype.destroy = function() {
  gl.deleteTexture(this.id);
  this.id = null;
};
```

Is there a limit in the number of Textures I can load on one page session? I only need to have around 200 in memory, the others I just destroy after use. Can it be that WebGL is not releasing the memory after I destroy a texture?

And to clarify that it's not an issue with the image itself, this error also happens if I just load the same image that number of times.

I'm testing it on the latest Chrome Canary.

Comment: There's shouldn't be a limit as long as you free the old ones. Do you need to free the old ones? Could instead you keep a pool of 200 textures around and just load new data into them (as a workaround)

Comment: That's actually a pretty good point... And it actually helped to get rid of some other WebGL warnings I was getting, but it didn't fixed this problem. I'll keep trying to figure it out.

Comment: Are your images different sizes? Is it possible you're fragmenting memory? For example if you had 4meg of ram and you allocated four 1meg chucks then freed the first and 3rd chunk you'd have 2meg free but you couldn't allocate 2 meg. I don't know if drivers work around this but shuffling the textures around or not. I'm assuming if you're doing something video like all the textures are the same size so it's not this. note: fiddle here that tests allocation lots of textures: http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/YCBqe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was unrelated to WebGL. The issue was a memory leak when loading the images. After I was done with them I was setting the textures to `null`, but not the `Image` objects. Simply adding `img = null` after I was done with them fixed the issue and Chrome isn't crashing anymore.

The confusion was that Chrome didn't throw an error when trying to load the image, and the `onload` callback was being called just fine, but then it would crash when trying to use that image. I'll file a bug report on Chromium, as I don't think this is the correct behavior (some other error should be thrown when an image can't be loaded).